# Unexpected end tag (font) HTML

Tags: html, r, nosuchmethoderror

I am running an R code to which several HTML files are connected. As R Returns an error message, I have opened the source file from which the message results:

In the HTML file, there is the following error message:

"End tag (font) violates step 1, paragraph 1 of the Adoption agency algorithm. Unexpected end tag (font). Ignored.

As I am completely new to HTML, I would appreciate if someone told me from which the message results. Here is the code line:

```
<TH ALIGN="left" COLSPAN="2">Methods in <A HREF="../../../../../../org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/package-summary.html">org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel</A> with parameters of type <A HREF="../../../../../../org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellType.html" title="enum in org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel">CellType</A></FONT></TH>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `</FONT>` tag  ... but you have not a beginner tag `<FONT>`

```
<TH ALIGN="left" COLSPAN="2">
    Methods in 
    <A HREF="../../../../../../org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/package-summary.html">org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel</A> 
    with parameters of type 
    <A HREF="../../../../../../org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellType.html" title="enum in org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel">CellType</A>
  </FONT>
</TH>
```

..so or you add the begin

```
<TH ALIGN="left" COLSPAN="2">
  <FONT
    Methods in 
    <A HREF="../../../../../../org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/package-summary.html">org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel</A> 
    with parameters of type 
    <A HREF="../../../../../../org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellType.html" title="enum in org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel">CellType</A>
  </FONT>
</TH>
```

or you should remove

```
<TH ALIGN="left" COLSPAN="2">
    Methods in 
    <A HREF="../../../../../../org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/package-summary.html">org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel</A> 
    with parameters of type 
    <A HREF="../../../../../../org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellType.html" title="enum in org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel">CellType</A>
</TH>
```